# Second order differential equation - complete solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am tasked with finding for all valid values of the constant a the complete solution for the differential equation:

$y''+2y'-3y=e^{ax}$

Now i am getting

$y(x) = e^{-3x}\cdot C2 + e^x \cdot C1 + \frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+2*a-3}$

We can see that $a^2+2*a-3 = 0$ at $a \in \{1, -3\}$
So the equation is not valid at that point.

Apperently this is not an acceptable answer and i have to find a solution for

$a=1$ or $a = -3$.

How do i do this? It seems impossible to me.

Comment: Which textbook are you following? Nearly every one I know indicates that when $a$ is a root of the characteristic equation (this is your case!), one should turn to the functions $xe^{ax}$, then $x^2e^{ax}$, and so on.

Comment: Since you already have $e^{-3x}$ and $e^x$, for the cases where $a=1$ or $a=-3$, you need to consider terms as $x e^{x}$ and $x e^{-3x}$.

Comment: How should i use these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the particular solution by parts of the homogeneous solution to finally read
$$
y_p(x)=\frac14\left(\frac{e^{ax}-e^x}{a-1}-\frac{e^{ax}-e^{-3x}}{a+3}\right)
$$
In this form it stays bounded also for values of $a$ close to the resonance cases. Obviously, in the case of $a\in\{-3,1\}$ one has to replace one of the quotients of the divided differences by the $a$-derivative $xe^{ax}$.